# Could be an odd integer number with repeat digits a prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, congruences, primality-test

I want to know more about primality test , this is one of my question to determine if an integer odd number could be prime with below property in the question.

> > **Question:**
> >     Could be an odd integer  number with repeat digits a prime ?
>
> **Note:** for example a number as this :$474747\cdots$

Comment: Do you consider something like $31313$? If not, then repeating the number $n$ gives a number divisible by $n$, so unless $n=1$ it is composite. Look up repunits.

Comment: If $n= \overline{abcd\dots}$ meaning that the number $abcd\dots$ repeats then $n$ is divisible by $abcd\dots$. E.g. $474747=10101\times47$

Comment: @ yes , i meant example :31313 , and i have a problem to formulate what i meant, for example :37377 i repeat the two digits and i keep one

Comment: $1111111111111111111$ is a prime number.

Comment: nice example you have

Comment: So you're talking about repeating a *group* of digits, not just one digit, right?

Comment: Take a look also at http://oeis.org/A173772

Comment: We cannot say much about when a general number with such a pattern is prime. It was already pointed out that a full nontrivial period cannot lead to a prime. I do not think that we can do much more.

Answer (score 1):

$$1717171717171717171717171717171$$ is an example with $31$ digits

Comment: Is that a repunits number ? if yes that is contradict that Repunit number can't be a prime , then i want if there is any known proof about that , and thanks for your nice example

Comment: and I upvote for this example

Comment: @zeraouliarafik No, a repunit number is a number consisting of only one digit, for example $777777$. The repunits containing only ones have been checked for primality, some primes were found, but noone knows whether infinite or finite many such primes exist.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about [repunits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit)?